# Product of two compact spaces with the product topology is compact

Tags: general-topology

The way I wanted to go about it was this. We have $X\times Y$ with the product topology, which in our case is equivalent to the box topology. If we take an open cover of $X\times Y$ ,$\{G_k\}_{k\in K}$ this will be made of unions of products of open sets in $X$ and $Y$. Let's take $F=\{U_i\times V_i | i\in I\}$ , where $U_i\times V_i$ are the products that make up the unions . Take $x\in X$ , then we know that $\{x\}\times Y$ is omeomorphic to $Y$ , meaning it is compact, so we can find a finite index set $I_x \subseteq I$ such that  $A=\{U_i\times V_i | i\in I_x\}$ is a finite subcover of $\{x\}\times Y$ . At this point, my book does it in a slightly different way, but what I did was this, in the same way, take $y\in Y$ , we can find a finite index set $I_y\subseteq I$ such that $B=\{U_j\times V_j | j\in I_y\}$ is a finite subcover of $X\times \{y\}$ . Now, if we take $A\cup B$ , this is a finite cover of $X\times Y$, and we also know that every element of $A\cup B$ is contained in some open set of the original open cover  $\{G_k\}_{k\in K}$ , so there are  a finite number of $k(i,j)\in K$ such that all of the $G_{k(i,j)}$ cover $X\times Y$ , and they are our finite subcover. Is this proof flawed in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid that it is flawed. Your set $A$ is a finite open cover of $\{x\}\times Y$, and your set $B$ is a finite open cover of $X\times\{y\}$, so $A\cup B$ is a finite open cover of

$$\big(\{x\}\times Y\big)\cup\big(X\times\{y\}\big)\,,$$

but there is no guarantee that it covers all of $X\times Y$, and in general it won’t. At this point in your argument you really have a different $A_x$ for each $x\in X$ and $B_y$ for each $y\in Y$.

Comment: You are definitely right, my set theory seems worse than I thought. Obviously an element (x,y) in X*Y doesn't have to be in that set, my intuition told me those sets were the same but they are obviously not. Now it makes more sense why my book did prove the theorem the way it did.